# Page fades out (but jumps back into view) before a new page loads + Safari back button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, fadeout

I use a little bit of javascript to fade out my page when a link is clicked before it redirects to a new page. The problem I'm having is the page fades out but then it quickly comes back into view for a split second before the page is redirected. As this refers to page redirection it's difficult to provide a CodePen example.

This seems to happen because of the `newpage` function I've included. I don't think I used this originally but I needed to put it in as sometimes when using the browser back button, especially on iOS safari, it would display a blank page.

This is the script I'm currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('[href*="website-url.com/"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $('body').fadeOut(150, newpage);
    });

    function newpage() {
        window.location = newLocation;
        $('body').show().removeClass('show-nav').addClass('hide-nav');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('body').removeClass('hide-nav');
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

The `.removeClass('show-nav').addClass('hide-nav');` bit refers to my full-page navigation I'm using. Clicking the back button in safari loads a page with the nav open by default. This is to force it to close it - though again, it does 'jump' a bit before it's hidden and you do catch a glimpse of it, if only for a fraction of a second.

Hope someone can help out with this!

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, i found a solution :
Just add :

```
$("body").html("");
```

This will empty the body, so nothing could appear then.

Here is your code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('[href*="website-url.com/"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $('body').fadeOut(1500, newpage);
    });

    function newpage() {
        $("body").html("");
        window.location = newLocation;
        $('body').show().removeClass('show-nav').addClass('hide-nav');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('body').removeClass('hide-nav');
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, the only problem I can see with that is it now brings back the original issue of that back button displaying a blank black in Safari (and I'm guessing iOS Safari). The end `setTimeout` function and `.removeClass('show-nav').addClass('hide-nav');` refers to this but it doesn't work now.

Comment: Could you please post your HTML / Css ? A JsFiddle could be interesting

Comment: I think the only problem with a CodePen/JsFiddle would we can't simulate page changes - or can you?

Comment: No I Can't but i would like to see the full code, in order to understand the problem.  Beceause during my tests i didn't have the issue you're reporting

Comment: Ah ok. This should hopefully help you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpMvpM Maybe it's something to do with pace.js?